# How to make player face consequences from killing enemy npcs in skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How to make player face consequences from killing enemy npcs in skyrim?

For example, if I kill a lonely bandit guarding the entrance to a bandit cave, and leave, a bandit party is dispatched to hunt me down in revenge of killing the lonely bandit?

Comment: Unfortunately, game- (and mod-)recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: Is it possible to move this question to the meta?

Comment: This question isn't any more valid on meta.  If you want something like this to work, rather than ask for a mod that meets certain criteria, tell us what problems you're facing, and that this mod solves.  From what I can tell, though, you want more gameplay mechanics added on top of the base game.  I'm afraid that's not really much of a problem we can help you with.

Comment: To avoid question closure, reword your question to ask for any solution instead of asking about a mod specifically. This is because some may see this as a recommendation question and vote to close as off-topic. (Not that I agree.) Related meta post: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5547/closed-mod-recommendation-skyrim-question-can-this-question-be-improved-and

Comment: Yep, as worded, this is no longer a mod recommendation.  Hopefully you find something that helps you!

Comment: The question has been changed from "Find me a mod that does X" to "How can I do X".  I fail to see how that makes it any more on-topic.  Now it's just a mod-recommendation in disguise.

Comment: @galacticninja Incidentally, a better meta to link to is: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8147/the-community-is-closing-mod-rec-questions, where we've decided that only questions that state a problem are ones we allow.  As for this rewording, while it describes an actual problem, I don't expect it to actually garner anything approaching quality answers.  Even with the focus on the problem (which isn't actually a problem in the game), I agree with BlueRaja; it's essentially a mod rec in disguise.

Answer (score 3):

No. I know nearly nothing about Mods and stuff, but as far as vanilla goes, you only receive repercussions (Hired thugs) for stealing things, trespassing, or murdering, but only in the case of civilians. Hope this helps.